# Unable to capture the exit code of ngspice, running in xterm window, in a PyQt4 script

Tags: python, pyqt4, xterm

I want to run ngspice through a xterm window in an application written in PyQt4. But I am not able to capture the exit signal of the ngspice process. I learned how to do the same for unix shell commands from the following link. But when I replace the shell command with ngspice, then the exit code is not getting propagated.

[How do I get the exit code of command and not xterm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8416596/how-do-i-get-the-exit-code-of-command-and-not-xterm)

Answer (score 0):

It will do (tested in a CYGWIN64 console window under MS Windows):

```
$ xterm -e sh -c 'ngspice ; echo $? > echo_status.txt'
```

ngspice opens up. Terminate ngspice with

quit 33

Then enter

```
cat echo_status.txt
```

to the console window, and the answer will be

```
33
```