# Exit code of a command in xterm

Tags: csh, xterm

From a `csh` script, I would like to open an `xterm` and execute a command and then access the return value by saving it in a file.

```
xterm -e "MyCommand; echo $? > ./log.txt"
```

This does not work. `$?` always returns `0` even if I replace `MyCommand` with something that does not exit.

I know this question is very similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8416596/how-do-i-get-the-exit-code-of-command-and-not-xterm) but it doesn't work for me. Perhaps because I am using csh here and `-c` flag does not exist in my environment.

How can I access the return value of the command itself and not the xterm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use single-quotes to prevent your current shell from expanding symbols, e.g.,

```
xterm -e 'MyCommand; echo $? > ./log.txt'
```